# Javascript won't let me set property which only has a getter despite deleting getter

Tags: javascript, getter

I have the following getter in one of my classes:

```
get password(){
        if(this._public) return null;

        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";    
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));   
        }

        delete this.password;
        return this.password = text;
}
```

There is no accompanying setter. On the line `return this.password = text` I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property password of # which has only a getter

However, the getter should be deleted at this point, and it should have no property called password. I actually took the idea from MDN's page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (the last code snippet on the page).

Anyone know why this is happening?

Tested on Chrome 51 and Node.js (v6.0.0).

Comment: Well, you can't set something if you have no setter, right? I think it's pretty obvious that you need a setter to actually set it

Comment: @Darkrifts: This is not Ruby. A property can be either data property or accessor property. If I understand correctly, OP wants to delete the accessor property so he can put a data property in its place.

Comment: How is the password stored in your class? this._password?

Comment: are you sure the error really comes from the line you think it comes from? I just tested the following on chrome: "var a = {get test(){delete this.test; return this.test = 123;} }; a.test" and it works.

Comment: Same as @Ness: here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g11t1cns/

Comment: @Ness: It seems to work for objects, but not for classes... https://jsfiddle.net/g11t1cns/1/ Could it be because the property is not on the object, so there's nothing to delete? and then when you try to set, you're still looking up the proto chain and getting the `password` getter defined by the class...

Comment: @Amadan - Ah, I see your edit includes what I was just posting. You should post an answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, sorry, I always press Enter prematurely, and have a thousand edits :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in comments, you can't delete what isn't there. `password` is not a property of `user`, but of its prototype; so `delete user.password` does nothing; if you then do `user.password = "foo"`, you will find the property `user` on the prototype, which is not settable.

Instead, you need to define a property on `user` itself:

```js
class User {
  get password() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "password", {
      value: "foo"
    });
    return this.password;
  }
};

var user = new User();
console.log(user.password);
```